# PHP Regexp Optimize An Existing Pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm using this code

```
preg_match_all("/([^#]+\btbds\b.+?)#/iu", $data, $matches);
```

to find all words named tbds, but its taking around 1.20 seconds to perform the pattern search. If I just use tbds\b instead of \btbds\b it takes just 0.19 seconds (6 times less).

```
preg_match_all("/([^#]+tbds\b.+?)#/iu", $data, $matches);
```

is there any way to optimize the word match \btbds\b  to take around 0.19 seconds? I need to process a large amount of data.

here is the test code:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = ' 0123 456 789 abcd efgh ijkl mn opqrstu vwx yzAB CDE FGHI JKL MNOP QRS TUVWX YZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    $randomString = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $randomString);
    return trim($randomString,' ');
}


$data=NULL;
for ($a = 1; $a < 1000000; $a++) 
    $data.=" ".generateRandomString(100)." #";


$t = microtime(true);
preg_match_all("/([^#]+\btbds\b.+?)#/iu", $data, $matches); 
echo microtime(true) - $t; echo "\n";
```

Comment: I need to process a large amount of data. Any help is welcomed :)

Comment: So, what do you want to do to this large amount of data, and why *must* it be done very quickly? Perhaps it could motivate us to help you, if we knew what you were trying to achieve? In other words: How can we optimize something we know nothing about?

Comment: Note that they don't match the same, as the one without `\b` will happily match `atbds #` while the other one will not

Comment: Might have a try with another approach: `$res = preg_grep('/\btbds\b/i', explode("#", $data));`

Comment: @Miguel perhaps you could help us to understand your _real_ input data because what you are generating randomly will never find a match -- there are no `#` symbols generated.  If you want us to design an optimized pattern for you, we need to fully understand the input variability.  Furthermore, you are performing unicode matching, but there are no unicode characters on offer.  Please improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

What makes your regex slow is the preceding `[^#]+`

Maybe it helps if you define a starting point which can be either `#` or *start of string* like this:

```
/(?:(?<=#)|^)([^#]*\btbds\b.+?)#/iu
```

[The Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GpU485/1)

Comment: I just tested your answer and its taking around 1.20 seconds.

Comment: I tested it at regex101 where it required about 1/10 steps and with your benchmark on php testing site where it also seemed considerably faster :)

Comment: hi frosti your regex /(?:(?<=#)|^)([^#]*\btbds\b.+?)#/iu is having a similar performance like my original regex /([^#]+\btbds\b.+?)#/iu . I'm trying to get a performance similar to /([^#]+tbds\b.+?)#/iu  around 0.19 seconds (6 times faster).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a possibility to match `#` and then using `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match.

Then match not a # one or more times with `[^#]+` and then your `tbds` between word boundaries `\btbds\b`.

[`#\K[^#]+\btbds\b[^#]+#`](https://regex101.com/r/viEaWq/2)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I just tested your suggestion and it seems to be having a performance  similar to the original /([^#]+\btbds\b.+?)#/iu

Comment: @Miguel Did you compare the number of steps on regex101 for a few examples?

Comment: yes its with very few steps compared to the original but in terms of performance when running the test code I get similar execution time around 1.20